# Why this multiselect code from loudev is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select

I want to include this : http://loudev.com/

I followed the steps but the code is not working. I also included jquery scripts because I suspect that might be required. I am not understanding where is the mistake.

Thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="something\jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<link href="something\css\multi-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#my-select').multiSelect();
console.log("why");
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
      <option value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
      <option value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
      <option value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
      <option value='elem_4'>elem 4</option>
      <option value='elem_5'>elem 5</option>
      <option value='elem_6'>elem 6</option>
      <option value='elem_7'>elem 7</option>

      <option value='elem_100'>elem 100</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```

on console I do get the "why" and there are no errors , then whats going wrong..why it is not working as it supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your JavaScript after your select box markup.
Also your source path seperators should be forward slashes "/" and not backslashes "\". e.g.

```
<script src="something\jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<link href="something\css\multi-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Should be

```
<script src="something/jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<link href="something/css/multi-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```